# CSS hover is not working, when I'm pointing mouse - nothing happens

Tags: html, css

For some reason CSS hover is not working.
I've tried to use negative z-index to hide behind divs that might be "covering" my element for hover(found it on some forum) but still the same.

The result I'm trying to achieve - when I hover mouse over animated elements on the right and left sides, it supposed to show 2 buttons which I should be able to use as a part of navbar.

```css
.header-container {}

.borderright {
  display: none;
  width: 250px;
  height: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0%;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  float: right;
}

.testright {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  right: 2%;
}

.testright:hover+.borderright {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="testright">
  This is the parent div which should trigger display:block with animated child
  <div class="dot-carousel">
    dot-carousel described in separate css file(animation)
  </div>
</div>

<div class="header-container">
  <div class="borderright">
    <div class="hero-image-right">
      <img src="assets/images/portfolio-dots.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="spanright">Hidden clickable button that should appear on hover</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have window.load nested? That makes no sense.... You should not have the loads inside

Comment: Ohh Boy, You have messed up the things with onload... window loads stuff once with all the images and content

Comment: I 've just copied the same script few times to make text animation continues into another text and then into another etc. Sorry guys, will try to find another way to replace words one by one. Do you think this might be related to my problem with hover?

Comment: This does not appear to meet the "Minimal" part of the [mcve]... please remove the unnecessary parts of the code until only enough to reproduce the issue is included.

Comment: Thank you TylerH, I've removed non necessary details. Now have only problem divs.

Comment: `.testright:hover + .borderright { ... }` Simple: `.borderright` is not an adjacent sibling of `.testright`. Educate yourself on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

Comment: Thank you connexo, i will then :)

Answer (score 1):

is this what you were trying to achieve?

```
.testright:hover + .header-container .borderright{
    display: block; 
}
```

The selector was targeting `.borderright` as a sibling of `.testright:hover` when `.borderright` is the child of the sibling element `.header-container`

Comment: Your answer would be alot more useful if you explained what mistake OP made.

Comment: Fair enough i'll explain a little better

Comment: Thank you IRLotsEvil, i hope so, however, it didn't help.
I think something else preventing it from selection. :( i will try to find out then

Comment: .borderright:hover{
  display: block;
} does adding this help? to keep the div displayed

Comment: Unfortunately .borderright:hover{ display: block; } didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector wasn't correct.

HTML

```
        <div class="testright">
            This is the parent div which should trigger display:block with animated child
            <div class="dot-carousel">dot-carousel described in separate css file(animation)</div>
        </div>

        <div class="header-container">
            <div class="borderright">
                <div class="hero-image-right">
                    <img src="assets/images/portfolio-dots.png" alt="" />
                </div>
                <a href="#"><span class="spanright">Hidden clickable button that should appear on hover</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.header-container {}

.borderright {
    display: none;
    width: 250px;
    height: 70px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0%;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
    float: right;
}

.testright {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: 2%;
}
.testright:hover + .header-container .borderright {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you simply use the **Copy snippet to answer** functionality?

Comment: I'm not sure where that is. This is day 3 for me on StackOverflow.

Comment: Press CTRL-F and then search this page for "Copy snippet to answer".

Comment: Neat! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks David, now i know that i made several mistakes, i will try to find out why it's still not working, something preventing it from selection i guess.